# Nepero game (by Yacov Perelman)

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, inequalities

I have already posted this question time before on stackexchange, but didn't receive a definitive solution.

So this is the game: consider a positive integer number $n$ and divide it in a finite number of parts $m$, then take the product of all the $m$ numbers you obtained and multiply them. For example for $n=10$ and $m=5$ the product will be $32$. The game consists in finding a number $m$ (positive integer) which maximize this product.

Now it's trivial to prove that the function $f(x)=(n/x)^x$, with $(0,+∞)$ as domain, increases on $(0,n/e]$ and decreases on $[n/e,+∞)$, so it has a max in $x=n/e$, thus you'll find the $m$ you're looking for by evaluating the function in the two integers nearest to $n/e$ and comparing these two values.

What is not easy to prove is that if you take the nearest positive integer to $n/e$ it will always be the best $m$ for the game, or at least for all the cases I've taken into consideration (with computational experiments too).

So my question is: how to prove (or disprove) that this fact holds for any positive integer $n$?

Comment: What exactly is the game? Are these supposed to be $m$ **equal** parts? Are they supposed to be integers? Then, you also have a divisibility condition.

Comment: Yes, they are $m$ equal parts (but I think it could be proved this other fact: to maximize the product they have to be all equals). The single parts are not necessarily integers, for example for $n=10$ and $m=3$ you get $(10/3)^3$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, even by not mentioning that, it follows from the geometric-arithmetic means inequality that the parts must be equals. But still have no idea of how to prove the theorem I'm asking for.

Comment: Suppose just for a moment that instead of taking $n$ to be an integer, you take $n=ke/2$, where $k$ is an odd integer.  Then $n/e$ is a half-integer, so the two choices for $m$ are equally close, but the higher of the two choices always gives a (slightly) better payoff --- in fact the ratio of the two payoffs goes rapidly to $1$ from above.  This suggests that when your $n/e$ is very close to a half-integer, there should be a slight preference for the larger of the two $m$'s, which is almost always outweighed by the strong preference for the closer one.....continued

Comment: continued --- so you might expect to find rare counterexamples when $n/e$ is just slightly less than a half-integer.

Comment: @ Steven Landsburg: this would seems to be the most plausible option, but couldn't find any counterexample. Also Jakov Perelman in his book states that for $n$ integer the theorem holds, but doesn't give proofs (it's not an academic book) or references, so it's not clear if he did really know for sure it was true or if his was just a guess.

Answer (score 4):

Good rational approximations to $e$ of the form $2n/(2m+1)$ provide candidates for counterexamples.  These are known from the continued fraction for $e$:
$$ 2 + \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{4+\dfrac{1}{1+ \ldots}}}}}}$$

But to have a counterexample, we would need (approximately)
$$ \left(m + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \dfrac{n}{e} \left(m + \dfrac{1}{2}\right) < \dfrac{1}{24}$$
and this does not appear to be the case: these will always be convergents where the next element of the continued fraction is $1$, so they are not especially good approximations, and it should be possible to prove that they are not good
enough.